# Multiple paragraph selection incorrect, to be changed using the textnode

Tags: javascript, html, range

I'm having problems running an action on more than one line.

In practice I do not get the desired effect and `<p>` tags are completely emptied of their content. This is the simple code I use, but it only works on a line:

Try to look at code in action [HERE](http://jsbin.com/janirocecu/1/edit?html,js,output) .
Follow the instructions in the example to understand the real problem.

```js
function press() {
  if (document.getSelection) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount < 1) {
      return;
    }
    var r = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = r.toString(),
      content = r.extractContents();
    span = document.createElement('span'),
      t = document.createTextNode(selectedText);
    selectedText = '';
    span.style.color = 'green';
    span.appendChild(t);
    r.insertNode(span);

    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Select only me for first: i don't have problems</p>
<p>Also select me at the same time of first paragraph, now i have problems..</p>
<button onclick="press()">Press after selecting the text</button>
```

Comment: Are you trying to just make them green? What is your actual goal?

Comment: My real goal is to add user data as if it were a text editor. In this case 'green' indicates the past color (the one chosen by the user).

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with node.js

Comment: You do know that you are trying to move all that text into a single span right? FYI A span and plain text will not maintain the integrity of a structured html document

Comment: @User you're trying to add the data where?

Comment: My goal is to modify the paragraphs.
The final goal is to have the same paragraphs by adding a span in the selected range. @John Smith I'm trying to add the text at the end of the first paragraph and the beginning of the second